# estimating P in Amdahl's Law

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

In parallel computing, Amdahl's law is mainly used to predict the theoretical maximum speedup for program processing using multiple processors. If we denote the speed up by S then Amdahl’s law is given by the formula:

***S=1/((1-P)+(P/N)***

where ***P*** is the proportion of a system or program that can be made parallel, and ***1-P*** is the proportion that remains serial. My question is how can we compute or estimate ***P*** for a given program ?

More specifically, my question has two parts:

- How can we compute ***P*** theoretically?
- How can we compute ***P*** in practice?

I know my question could be easy but I am learning.

ref : https://www.techopedia.com/definition/17035/amdahls-law

Comment: I think this question may be more appropriate for computer science stackexchange due to its theoretical nature.